# Using labview to control multi computers

Tags: windows, labview

I am using labview to control 6 machines each of which is with a computer and independent code.

I want to control 6 machines at the same time by one monitor.

Can I use web serve?

Or does anyone have another good idea?

Answer (score 1):

There are many options to do this, depending on what you want.

To share data look in the "data binding" section of the properties and set up a shared variable engine. If the data is not that time-sensitive, I'd recommend writing it to a shared directory for simplicity.

To share screens you would be better served by a remote desktop connection.

Answer (score 1):

I have found in my development as a Certified LabVIEW Architect, that shared variables are highly problematic. My former company prohibited their use, for that reason. You're better off using the standard TCP/IP example code, and setting up custom clusters that you flatten to strings.

[EDIT] NI has now put out Time-Sensitive-Networking (TSN). If you're still working on this problem, TSN might be able to help you out, especially if you have any time-critical loops or other RT code executing.

Answer (score 0):

Shared variables might be your easiest solution. Although they are implemented over TCP, they act like multicast UDP, allowing for all machines to see all data (if you desire).  They are as easy as wiring data into a local variable in a block diagram.

The hardest part about using Shared Variables is your windows firewall settings.  They are almost always blocking these ports, so check the NI documentation to determine which ports to open.